# Экранирование знака вопроса ? regex c#

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

```
"(?<=href=\"/url?q).*"
```

вот такая вот регулярка
долго ломал голову почему ничего не находит, хотя в тексте всё в точности, стал перепроверять посимвольно и не находит, только когда доходит до этого знака вопроса. при попытке заэкранировать его \ символом - студия пишет, что нераспознанная эскейп последовательность.
часть кода (хотя он тут не оч поможет):

```
Regex domen = new Regex("(?<=href=\"/url?q).*");
                        if (domen.IsMatch(answer) != false)
                        {
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В регулярках все символы экранируются обратным слешём. Но поскольку сам слеш в строках тоже может требовать экранирования, его может понадобиться удвоить. Но гораздо удобнее использовать особаченные строки:

```
new Regex(@"href=""/url\?q(.*?)""");
```

Comment: спасибо! с двойным слешем мне как-то удобнее. странно - почему кавычки экранируются одним слешем, а для знака вопроса - надо два слеша